# How to handle exception in blueprint route in camel project

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I am working on camel project using JbossFuse. Here I am using blueprint. Now what I want is that when any exception comes in any of the route then that will be handled by some processor and a valid response will be returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can cover any of the route in blueprint file with try catch and process the final response to the client. The logic will be something like:

```
<route id="route_1">
    <from id="_from_1" uri="direct:processDemo1"/>
    <doTry id="_doTryDemo1">
        <process id="_process_processDemo1" ref="processorBean"/>
        <doCatch id="_doCatchDemo1">
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <to id="_handleExceptionDemo1" uri="direct:HandleException_demo1"/>
        </doCatch>
        <doFinally id="_doFinallyDemo1">
            <log id="_log_Demo1Process_finally" message="Demo1 operation completed"/>
        </doFinally>
    </doTry>
</route>
```

Here `processorBean` is the Bean class to process Demo1 route and `uri="direct:HandleException_demo1"` is an another route which will be called if there is exception comes in Demo1 route. So the exception route will be for this route will be

```
<route id="routeDemo1Exception">
    <from id="_fromdemo1Exception" uri="direct:HandleException_demo1"/>
    <log id="log_demo1Exception" message="Demo1 Exception called"/>
    <process id="_process_exception_Demo1" ref="processDemo1ExceptionBean"/>
</route>
```